# How to randomize the speed of rotating circle?

Tags: javascript, html, random, settimeout

I have two circles rotating round the circle and I would like the circle to change the speed at random after passing one revolution.Both circle should be at different speed or they might be the same speed (then collision will occurs). For example, during first run, both circles are moving at 10m/s and after it reaches end of the revolution,they will collide.Let's say after the revolution, it changes circle 1 to 15m/s and circle 2 to 30m/s , then they won't collide.I would like to know how to achieve this. This is just an idea of what i am trying to achieve. It would be even better if the speed is randomized after every revolution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```js
(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    x1 = 160,
    y1 = 120,
    x2 = 330,
    y2 = 280,
    radius = 20;
  angle = 0,
    velX = 0,
    velY = 0,
    thrust = 3,
    rotation = 0;

  function draw() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x1 += velX;
    y1 += velY;
    angle += 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    draw2();
    setTimeout(function() {
      draw()
    }, 30);
  }

  function draw2() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x2 += -velX;
    y2 += -velY;
    angle += 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#80ced6";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    collisiondetection();
  }

  var distance = 0;
  var totalcounter = 0;
  var collide = false;

  function collisiondetection() {
    distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

    if (distance < radius * 2) {
      if (collide == false) {
        totalcounter = totalcounter + 1;
        document.getElementById("cTotal").innerHTML = "Total collisions:" + totalcounter;
        collide = true;
      }

    } else {
      collide = false;
    }

  }
  draw();
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>
<span id="cTotal">Total collisions: </span>
```

Comment: Welcome. You are supposed to show your code and tell us what exactly is wrong with it and not working as you intend.

Comment: How about. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);     // returns a random integer from 0 to 100` ? Just generate a random `speed` number after spin.

Comment: Just declare a variable speed and make it random, and send the value to the `setTimeout(function(){draw()}, speed)`

Comment: I don't follow your explanation

Comment: I tried your advise on declaring a speed variable and making it random. The thing is the two circles always "collide" in every revolution. The idea is both circles are having different speed in different revolution so they may collide or may not collide. I hope I make sense

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara it will not change the speed after a revolution, but just after one call of the function `draw()`.

Comment: or you can do something like declare it,  and update the `speed` in `collisiondetection()`

Comment: I think the best way is to make random speed for two different circle so they might collide or might not collide. That's the idea i am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `timeGap` when `angle` becomes 360, i.e., when a revolution completes. Thus, it will appear as the speed is getting changed.

Inside your `draw()` function:

```
if(angle % 360 == 0) {
    timeGap = Math.random() * 20 + 5;
}
```

```js
(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    x1 = 160,
    y1 = 120,
    x2 = 330,
    y2 = 280,
    radius = 20,
    angle1 = 0,
    angle2 = 0,
    velX = 0,
    velY = 0,
    thrust = 3,
    rotation = 0,
    timeGap1 = 10,
    timeGap2 = 10,
    diff = 20,
    minTimeGap = 20;

  function draw() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle1 * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle1 * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x1 += velX;
    y1 += velY;
    angle1 += 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    
    if(angle1 % 360 == 0) {
        timeGap1 = Math.random() * diff + minTimeGap;
    }
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      draw();
    }, timeGap1);
  }

  function draw2() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle2 * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle2 * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x2 += -velX;
    y2 += -velY;
    angle2 += 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#007700";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    if(angle2 % 360 == 0) {
        timeGap2 = Math.random() * diff + minTimeGap;
    }    
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      draw2();
    }, timeGap2);
  }
  
  function clearCanvas() {
   ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
    collisiondetection();
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      clearCanvas();
    }, timeGap2 + timeGap1);
  }

  var distance = 0;
  var totalcounter = 0;
  var collide = false;

  function collisiondetection() {
    distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

    if (distance < radius * 2) {
      if (collide == false) {
        totalcounter = totalcounter + 1;
        document.getElementById("cTotal").innerHTML = "Total collisions:" + totalcounter + "<br/>Speed1: " + timeGap1 + "<br/>Speed2: " + timeGap2;
        collide = true;        
      }

    } else {
      collide = false;
    }
  }
  draw();
  draw2();
  clearCanvas();
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>
<span id="cTotal">Total collisions: </span>
```

Comment: But both circles will always collide after every revolution.

Comment: @TomCold I just updated my answer to remove the collision dependance.

Comment: does it mean both circles are going at diff speed?

Comment: Doesn't work, both circles will always collide in every revolution.

Comment: @TomCold, I said that both circles will have different speed (as compared to previous revolution, but both revolve at same speed with respect to to each other). It works good for me, what doesn't work for you, i don't know. Can you explain more?

Comment: What I want is everytime the circle completes one revolution, it will collide with the other circle. I believe although the speed is changing but circles are having the same speed. I want each circle to have different speed at random so they don't collide in revolution, they can also collide if they happen to do with same speed.

Comment: Could you send me an animation gif of how it works for you? So maybe I could explain what is wrong.

Comment: Ok. I will try to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181055/discussion-between-rv7-and-tomcold).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to declare a local `speed` variable to the `draw()` function, then pass it to the `setTimeout()` callback, like this:

```
var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
draw2();
setTimeout(function() {
    draw()
}, speed);
```

The code `Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)` will give you a random number between `0` and `10` so `setTimeout` will be called with a different speed each time.

**Demo:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  (function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
      x1 = 160,
      y1 = 120,
      x2 = 330,
      y2 = 280,
      radius = 20;
    angle = 0,
      velX = 0,
      velY = 0,
      thrust = 3,
      rotation = 0;

    function draw() {
      velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
      velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
      x1 += velX;
      y1 += velY;
      angle += 1;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

      var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      draw2();
      setTimeout(function() {
        draw()
      }, speed);
    }

    function draw2() {
      velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
      velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
      x2 += -velX;
      y2 += -velY;
      angle += 1;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#80ced6";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();

      collisiondetection();
    }

    var distance = 0;
    var totalcounter = 0;
    var collide = false;

    function collisiondetection() {
      distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

      if (distance < radius * 2) {
        if (collide == false) {
          totalcounter = totalcounter + 1;
          document.getElementById("cTotal").innerHTML = "Total collisions:" + totalcounter;
          collide = true;
        }

      } else {
        collide = false;
      }

    }
    draw();
  })();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>
<span id="cTotal">Total collisions: </span>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that after every iteration, the two circle always "collide". What I am trying to achieve is probably if two circles have different speed(at random), so they might collide or might not. Is that possible?

Comment: No, don't ever call a drawing method from an animation loop with random intervals. A drawing method should be synchronised to the screen refresh rate.

Comment: @TomCold Actually this is not quite clear, what you are asking, you were looking for a random speed, right? You need it to be different for the two circles?

Comment: @chŝdk Maybe my question wasn't clear. But i edited it for clearance. Because if both circles are moving at different speed, then they won't collide else they will collide. So my point is i want both circles to have random speed ( they both don't need to have same speed ) , if they do then they will collide which is fine. The whole point is i am trying to simulate how many times in random a collision would occur. Your answer above changes speed for both circles so collusion will always occur.

Comment: Actually it's not the speed who will prevent the collision, it's the rect and angle who give the collision, that's because you are giving the same values.

Answer (score -1):

```js
(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    x1 = 160,
    y1 = 120,
    x2 = 330,
    y2 = 280,
    radius = 20;
  angle = 0,
    velX = 0,
    velY = 0,
    thrust = 3,
    rotation = 0,  
    maxSpeed = 100,      
    speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  function draw() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x1 += velX;
    y1 += velY;
    angle += 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1, y1, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    draw2();
    SpeedCount();
  }

  function draw2() {
    velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
    x2 += -velX;
    y2 += -velY;
    angle += 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#80ced6";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x2, y2, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    collisiondetection();
  }
  
  function SpeedCount(){
  (function(speed) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      draw()
    }, speed);
  })(speed);
}


  var distance = 0;
  var totalcounter = 0;
  var collide = false;

  function collisiondetection() {
    distance = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

    if (distance < radius * 2) {
      if (collide == false) {
        totalcounter = totalcounter + 1;
        document.getElementById("cTotal").innerHTML = "Total collisions:" + totalcounter;
        collide = true;
      }

    } else {
      collide = false;
    }
    
    if((angle + 90) % 360 == 0){   
         speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxSpeed) + 1;
    }

  }
  draw();
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>
<span id="cTotal">Total collisions: </span>
```

try this one.

Answer (score -1):

Let's rework it a bit:

First, when programming a graphical animation, you should separate your objects logic and your drawing operations.

The drawing operations should occur at regular intervals, based on the screen refresh rate (to avoid drawing sometimes twice a frame and sometimes not drawing at all).

A convenient method available in the Web API for this exact case is [requestAnimationFrame(callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). It will queue our callback to fire just before the next screen refresh rate.
So we can use it as the core of our animation loop, that will always fire at the same rate as our screen can show (usually 60FPS).

When you have animated objects on your scene, the simplest data-structure in js, are Objects. Instead of holding a lot of variables everywhere, you pack them in their own object.
When you have multiple such objects, you hold them all together (e.g in an Array).

Now, in our animation loop, we will first update our objects position, then draw them.
It is in the update part that we will control the velocity of our objects, and only after we did update all the object, we will check if they collide.

```js
(function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),

    max_speed = Math.PI / 12,
    objects = [{
        center_x: 160,
        center_y: 120,
        speed: Math.random() % max_speed,
        angle: 0,
        color: '#000'
      },
      {
        center_x: 330,
        center_y: 280,
        speed: -(Math.random() % max_speed),
        angle: 0,
        color: "#80ced6"
      }
    ],
    radius = 20,
    outerRad = 120,
    totalcounter = 0,
    collide = true;

  anim(); // begin our main anim loop

  function anim() {
    update(); // our objects update logic
    draw(); // now we draw
    collisiondetection(); // DOM update
    requestAnimationFrame(anim); // start again @next-frame
  }


  function update() {
    // here we only change the object's properties
    // nothing graphical should come here
    objects.forEach(function(object) {
      var angle = object.angle;
      object.x = Math.cos(angle) * outerRad + object.center_x;
      object.y = Math.sin(angle) * outerRad + object.center_y;
      object.angle += object.speed;
    });
  }

  function draw() {
    // here is only the graphical part
    // no logic should come here
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 550, 400);
    objects.forEach(function(object) {
      ctx.fillStyle = object.color;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    });
  }

  function collisiondetection() {
    var o1 = objects[0],
      o2 = objects[1];
    var distance = Math.sqrt((o1.x - o2.x) * (o1.x - o2.x) + (o1.y - o2.y) * (o1.y - o2.y));

    if (distance < radius * 2) {
      if (collide == false) {
        totalcounter = totalcounter + 1;
        document.getElementById("cTotal").innerHTML = "Total collisions:" + totalcounter;
        collide = true;
      }

    } else {
      collide = false;
    }

  }

  // and now if you want to update randomly these object's speed, you can do from anywhere
  document.onclick = function() {
    objects[0].speed = Math.random() % max_speed;
    objects[1].speed = -(Math.random() % max_speed);
  };

})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="background:#eee;"></canvas>
<p id="cTotal">Total collisions: </p>
```